# How do I iteratively append to text?

Tags: python, pandas, text, append, iteration

I have a dataframe that needs to be appended upto page/9/ in python

```
df:

/soccer/england/premier-league-2020-2021/results/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/
```

For every row in `df` , I have to append `page/#/`, `page/2/`, `page/3/`, `page/4/`, etc upto `page/9/` as below

How can I do it in python?

expected df:

```
/soccer/england/premier-league-2020-2021/results/#/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2020-2021/results/#/page/2/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2020-2021/results/#/page/3/
.
.
/soccer/england/premier-league-2020-2021/results/#/page/9/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/page/2/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/page/3/
.
.
/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/#/page/9/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/2/
/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/3/
.
.
/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/#/page/9/
```

Comment: I didn't get you?

Comment: I have scraped a list of parent URLs which have subsequent child URLs which cannot be scraped as they are dynamically generated. I am trying to generate the children iteratively  hence this question. I want a `/#/page/n/` added to every row in dataframe upto `/#/page/9/` while page 1 is always `/#/`

Comment: @Sujay edited my question. Does it explain better?

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample dataframe used by me:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col': {0: '/soccer/england/premier-league-2020-2021/results/',
  1: '/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/',
  2: '/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/',
  3: '/soccer/england/premier-league-2020-2021/results/',
  4: '/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/',
  5: '/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/',
  6: '/soccer/england/premier-league-2020-2021/results/',
  7: '/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/',
  8: '/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/',
  9: '/soccer/england/premier-league-2020-2021/results/',
  10: '/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/',
  11: '/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results/'}})
```

You can try:

```
df['h']=df.index%9+1
#created a helper column
df['col']=df['col']+("#/page/"+df['h'].astype(str)+'/').mask(df['h'].eq(1),"#/")
#conditionally adding '"/#/page/pagenumber/"' and '#/'
df=df.drop('h',1)
#remove that helper column
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your desired output

### Update:

IIUC you need 9 url for every unique url so:

```
out=pd.DataFrame(df['col'].unique(),columns=['col'])
#created a dataframe from the unique values of 'col' column
out=out.reindex(out.index.repeat(9)).reset_index(drop=True)
#repeated values of each row 9 times
out['h']=out.index%9+1
#created a helper column
out['col']=out['col']+("#/page/"+out['h'].astype(str)+'/').mask(out['h'].eq(1),"#/")
#conditionally adding '"/#/page/pagenumber/"' and '#/'
out=out.drop('h',1)
#remove that helper column
```

Now If you print `out` you will get your desired output

Comment: This is close. I edited `df['col']=df['col']+("/#/page/"+df['h'].astype(str)+'/').mask(df['h'].eq(1),"/#/")` to `df['col'] = df['col'] + ("#/page/" + df['h'].astype(str) + '/').mask(df['h'].eq(1), "/#/")` and pages where there are numbers is as expected however I am getting `/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results//#/  ` where `/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations/results/#/  ` is expected. one extra `/` How can I edit it? Thank you **SO** much!

Comment: @PyNoob_N updated answer....kindly have a look(removed \ in mask) ***:)***

Comment: Sorry to recheck, the above code appends a subsequent `/#/page/n/` to the URL however I am looking to have 9 URLs for every URL right? I am sorry to have overlooked this. Can you please look into it. I am very bad at developer logic and sorry if I am not able to explain it precisely.

Comment: @PyNoob_N updated answer....kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 1):

You can just run a simple loop:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
liks_with_pages = []
for lid,link in enumerate(df['Duration'].tolist()):
  page_num = lid%9 + 1
  if page_num == 1:
    suffix = '#/'
  else:
    suffix = '#/page/' + str(page_num) + '/'
  liks_with_pages.append(str(link)+suffix)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
processed = dict()
for URL in URLS:
    if URL not in processed:
        processed[URL] = 1
        print(url)
    else:
        processed[URL] = processed[URL]+1
        print(url+f'/page/{processed[URL]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
year_results = [
    "/soccer/england/premier-league-2020-2021/results",
    "/soccer/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results",
    "/soccer/england/premier-league-2018-2019/results",
]
sub_pages = []
for year_res in year_results:
    for page in range(1, 10):
        if page != 1:
            page = f"page/{page}/"
        else:
            page = ''
        sub_pages.append(f"{year_res}/#/{page}")
```

or equivalently:

```
sub_pages = [f"{year_res}/#/{f'page/{page}/' if page!=1 else ''}" for year_res in year_results for page in range(1, 10)]
```